# Issue with Returning Results SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue INT
DECLARE @Field1 VARCHAR(50)

SET @Field1 = (SELECT Field1 
               FROM [Workflow Creation].[dbo].[ssFields] 
               WHERE Field1 = 'Gary')

IF @Field1 = 'Gary' OR @Field1 = 'Sarah'
    SET @ReturnValue = '1'
ELSE 
    SET @ReturnValue = '0';
```

Essentially I want to Return a value and then set that value. I am working with program, that is very touchy feely on what it returns. So I get this error in SQL Management Studio:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Below is what I had before, it would return results, but the program would not take the results and properly assign it where i needed these files to go.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(CASE       
            WHEN Field1 = 'Gary' OR Field1 = 'Sarah'            
               THEN 1                 
               ELSE 0   
         END AS BIT) AS [ReturnValue], 
    * 
FROM 
    [Workflow Creation].[dbo].[ssfields];
```

Thanks,

JimmyDean

Comment: This is a bit unclear. How many rows are in your ssFields table? Which row do you want to read from? I see that you want ReturnValue to be 1 or 0, but in what circumstance exactly? Your old query would potentially return many rows. You need to make clearer what the business rules are which you're trying to implement.

Comment: The actual error is specifically because `SELECT Field1 
               FROM [Workflow Creation].[dbo].[ssFields] 
               WHERE Field1 = 'Gary'` can potentially return multiple rows. Clearly you can't assign a multi-row resultset to a single `varchar` variable, it doesn't make any sense and SQL is telling you that. What you haven't made clear is what should happen instead.

Comment: @ADyson So it will be returning 60+ rows, I suppose I would only want it to return 1 row and 1 column. I am not sure how I can do that, still trying to figure out SQL and was able to get this far.

Comment: @ADyson What I want the query to do is create a ReturnValue for one document and then send that document accordingly. I have to go through a whole process and the way the program is designed they don't have it where each table field is in a different location. So where the document sits it sits in the same pool as the other documents I don't want to move. So I have a process where it pulls all the documents I want and pushes them, but in order to do that I want them to go in separate ways not the same direction.

Comment: iID ArchiveID DocID Field00 Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5 Field9 Field10 Field11 Field12 Field13 Field14 Field15
36 1 39 NULL Gary MacDonald 09/10/1979 047-80-0001 NULL Denied 111.11 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
38 1 41 NULL Sarah Franklin 05/11/1984 044-84-4444 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL

Comment: "I would only want it to return 1 row and 1 column"...but which one? How will you decide which row to select in any particular execution of the program? You haven't told us what the criteria are. Once you've got some criteria, you can write a WHERE clause for your query such that it only selects the row you need.

Comment: P.S. re your "what I want to do" comment...I have no idea what any of this means in the context of a SQL query. Without the wider context of your organisation, business rules, other applications etc this is entirely meaningless to me or anyone else reading it, sorry. I have no idea how any of it relates to the SQL above. Try to focus on the specifics of your problem. All we really need to know in order to fix the SQL is: what the input data looks like, what the rules for processing are and what the output should look like. A worked example would really help to illustrate it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason why you're getting that error is because you can only assign one item to your @Field1 variable. SQL Server thinks you're trying to assign multiple nvarchars to the same @Field1 variable. Here's how to fix your query:

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue INT
DECLARE @Field1 VARCHAR(50)

SET @Field1 = (SELECT TOP 1 Field1 
               FROM YourTable
               WHERE Field1 = 'Gary')

IF @Field1 = 'Gary' OR @Field1 = 'Sarah'
    SET @ReturnValue = '1'
ELSE 
    SET @ReturnValue = '0';

SELECT @ReturnValue --will be 1
```

When you use `SELECT TOP 1 Field1 FROM YourTable` you are explicitly telling SQL Server to take the top record returned and assign the Column result for Field1 to your variable @Field1.

If you have multiple results you want to capture then a temp table could do it:

```
CREATE TABLE #Field1s (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    IsGaryOrSarah BIT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Field1s
SELECT CASE WHEN Field1 = 'Gary' THEN 1
            WHEN Field1 = 'Sarah' THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END
FROM YourTable
SELECT * FROM #Field1s
```

However if the intent is to do some operation based on the result as part of a workflow then you would almost certainly want to do that from application code. You would query the table from the application and you can more easily implement a conditional logic workflow using a language designed for that task.

Comment: I will give this a try. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Selected your answer because in the end it returned the best result. Thank you for being able to decipher through the vague description and still be able to figure it out! in the end, this was something I knew probably wouldn't work because of how the program is and will probably have to go with configuring a few things in the program. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem are these lines:

```
DECLARE @Field1 VARCHAR(50)

SET @Field1 = (SELECT Field1 
               FROM [Workflow Creation].[dbo].[ssFields] 
               WHERE Field1 = 'Gary')
```

`@Field1` is a `VARCHAR` value (not a `TABLE` variable) and your select is returning multiple rows because in table `ssFields` there is more than 1 row with `Field1 = 'Gary'`. This is why you get the error message:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value

To fix this you can use a `TOP 1` inside the `SELECT`. This will always return either 0 or 1 row (and never more) and this message won't pop.

```
DECLARE @Field1 VARCHAR(50)

SET @Field1 = (SELECT TOP 1 Field1                        -- Here
               FROM [Workflow Creation].[dbo].[ssFields] 
               WHERE Field1 = 'Gary')
```

---

However, I believe that this is actually what you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue INT
DECLARE @Field1 VARCHAR(50) = 'Gary'

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 'the searched field exists!!'
            FROM [Workflow Creation].[dbo].[ssFields] 
            WHERE Field1 = @Field1)
BEGIN
    SET @ReturnValue = 1 -- Don't use literals if it's a number!
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @ReturnValue = 0 -- Don't use literals if it's a number!
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Really appreciated the help! I did give a good reputation because it was helpful in understanding what I needed to fix!

Comment: From [Constants](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "A constant, also known as a literal or a scalar value, is a symbol that represents a specific data value. The format of a constant depends on the data type of the value it represents." Using a _literal_ value of the correct data type is a good thing, e.g. `declare @Result as Int = 0;` rather than `'0'`. A curious case is `declare @Result as Bit = 'false';`. ("The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.")